# Installing docker-ce in Ubuntu 18.04 breaks internet connectivity of host

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, dns, docker

I've installed `docker` on a fresh ubuntu desktop 18.04 machine and I lost internet connection in the host immediately after the installation finished. More specifically, I can `ping 8.8.8.8` but I can't `ping www.google.com`.

The steps to reproduce the error are the following:

1. Install ubuntu 18.04
2. [Install docker-ce](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/) using a local DNS server.

EDIT:

The most important difference between a clean install and my situation is that my machine is using a local DNS server, which has a fixed address at `172.17.100.3` and `172.17.100.70` in a corporate network.

From what I've read so far, either the problem comes from `NetworkManager`'s attempt to manage the `docker0` interface **or** *something* in the docker installation process breaks `systemd` resolve capabilities. Note that `systemd-resolve` [uses 127.0.0.53 by default](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-resolved.service.html)

So far I've attempted the following:

- Hardcoding `nameserver 8.8.8.8` in `/etc/resolv.conf` works
- Uninstalling docker fixes this problem. Installing/removing docker does not change `resolv.conf`.
- Removing `dnsmasq` from `/etc/NetworkingManager.conf`: I used this solution as I show here https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/36153, which shows the same problem on ubuntu 16.04. My fresh installation of 18.04 does not have this line, so this fix is not valid anymore.
- Docker docs suggest [*disabling or removing `NetworkManager`* completely](https://success.docker.com/article/should-you-use-networkmanager) as shown in https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/#dns-resolver-found-in-resolvconf-and-containers-cant-use-it but I'm not sure if this refers to my problem. I also don't know if this will break other stuff.
- [This suggests disabling management](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30343) for `docker0` https://gist.github.com/lanrat/458066dbdeb460b9cef40dc2af639a24 but it does not fix the problem in my case
- This approach suggest something different https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/32836 but I believe is not related to this problem

So far the only thing that works is hardcoding the google dns server address in `resolv.conf`, which is not a clean approach in my opinion. I also have to automate this process on startup, which is something I don't like.

How does one properly fix the NetworkingManager problem in a development machine that has docker?

### Current environment

My default `resolv.conf` has

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

and `systemd-resolve --status` returns (I've checked with a colleague and we have the same output)

```
Global
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 4 (docker0)
      Current Scopes: none
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 3 (eno1)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 172.17.100.3
                      172.17.100.70

Link 2 (eno2)
      Current Scopes: none
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
```

ifconfig docker0

```
bluesmonk@laptop:/etc/NetworkManager$ ifconfig docker0
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:86:e0:f0:94  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

and the status of the `docker service`

```
$ sudo service docker status
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2018-07-03 10:17:35 -04; 4min 52s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 14992 (dockerd)
    Tasks: 31
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
           ├─14992 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd://
           └─15015 docker-containerd --config /var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.toml

jul 03 10:17:32 laptop dockerd[14992]: time="2018-07-03T10:17:32.981563020-04:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support swap memory limit"
jul 03 10:17:32 laptop dockerd[14992]: time="2018-07-03T10:17:32.981595408-04:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period"
jul 03 10:17:32 laptop dockerd[14992]: time="2018-07-03T10:17:32.981603807-04:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime"
jul 03 10:17:32 laptop dockerd[14992]: time="2018-07-03T10:17:32.982040899-04:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
jul 03 10:17:34 laptop dockerd[14992]: time="2018-07-03T10:17:34.403909997-04:00" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used
jul 03 10:17:35 laptop dockerd[14992]: time="2018-07-03T10:17:35.083366302-04:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
jul 03 10:17:35 laptop dockerd[14992]: time="2018-07-03T10:17:35.458766295-04:00" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=9ee9f40 graphdriver(s)=overlay2 version=18.03.1-ce
jul 03 10:17:35 laptop dockerd[14992]: time="2018-07-03T10:17:35.458857295-04:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
jul 03 10:17:35 laptop dockerd[14992]: time="2018-07-03T10:17:35.470042819-04:00" level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock"
jul 03 10:17:35 laptop systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
lines 1-20/20 (END)
```

Related to my machine

```
Client:
 Version:      18.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.37
 Go version:   go1.9.5
 Git commit:   9ee9f40
 Built:        Wed Jun 20 21:43:51 2018
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
 Orchestrator: swarm

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:      18.03.1-ce
  API version:  1.37 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.9.5
  Git commit:   9ee9f40
  Built:        Wed Jun 20 21:42:00 2018
  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
  Experimental: false
```

docker info:

```
docker info
Containers: 1
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 1
Images: 1
Server Version: 18.03.1-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 773c489c9c1b21a6d78b5c538cd395416ec50f88
runc version: 4fc53a81fb7c994640722ac585fa9ca548971871
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.15.0-23-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 31.38GiB
Name: bluesmonk-ubuntu
ID: FRUH:57KI:POWV:EAHH:CY6Y:J3UH:OWBH:AIYF:BONF:DH4Q:5Y2P:RZ6T
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support
```

about the distro

```
$ cat /etc/*release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

Probably related

- https://development.robinwinslow.uk/2016/06/23/fix-docker-networking-dns/
- https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/23910
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35693117/how-can-i-give-docker-containers-access-to-a-dnsmasq-local-dns-resolver-on-the-h

Thanks!

ps: I've opened a question in the docker forums with the same info https://forums.docker.com/t/cant-access-internet-after-installing-docker-in-a-fresh-ubuntu-18-04-machine/53416

Comment: Does your host have an interface *on the same network* as the DNS server?  What is the address that docker assigns to the `docker0` interface?

Comment: Adresses of DNS Servers are `172.17.100.3` and  `172.17.100.70` and if I'm answering your question right, `ip a show docker0` (or `ifconfig docker0`) shows `inet 172.17.0.1/16`

Comment: and `ip a show eno2` which is my host interface shows `inet 172.16.254.111/25`

Comment: More answers here, but this is a really frustrating problem to work around especially for a vpn: https://serverfault.com/questions/916941/configuring-docker-to-not-use-the-172-17-0-0-range

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So here's your problem:

Docker has assigned the range `172.17.0.1/16` to your `docker0` interface. This includes all addresses from `172.17.0.1` through `172.17.255.255`. You will note that this range includes your DNS servers (`172.17.100.3` and `172.17.100.70`).  What you have is a routing problem:

Whenever you host needs to reach your DNS servers, it sees that it has an interface already on the same network (`docker0`), so it tries to route packets using that interface...which of course go nowhere, which is why your DNS stops working.

Docker doesn't have a simple mechanism for excluding an address range from it's automatic selection process, so you'll probably need to do two things to resolve the problem:

First, explicitly set the address of `docker0` in your `/etc/docker/daemon.json`.  Use any network that doesn't conflict your internal networks.  E.g.:

```
{
  "bip": "172.31.0.1/16"
}
```

You'll need to restart Docker.

Next, to prevent Docker from selecting the same network range for a user defined network (one that you create explicitly using `docker network create` or implicitly using, e.g., `docker-compose` or `docker stack ...`), create a new network and then never use it:

```
docker network create --subnet 172.17.0.0/16 --config-only do_not_use
```

This should both resolve your problem and prevent it from cropping back up in the future.

**Update**

Docker actually documents an arguably better way of accomplishing this in [How do I influence which network address ranges Docker chooses during a 'docker network create'?](https://success.docker.com/article/how-do-i-influence-which-network-address-ranges-docker-chooses-during-a-docker-network-create).

This requires setting persistent static routes on your system, which
varies between Linux distributions.

Comment: I'm adding this for the sake of completeness. After changing `"bip"`, some stray networks left were still conflicting with my DNS (and later I found out also with the VPN server) So I did the following:

1. stopped containers using those networks
2. `docker network prune` until no conflicting network remained
3. next time I run `compose up` it would fail because some networks were obviously missing, so I did `compose up --force-recreate`

Comment: I am running into this same exact case on 18.04. We have 16.04 systems that this does NOT happen on. Why?

Comment: I'm not sure but my guess is that network management works differently between versions of Ubuntu

Comment: I'm having this problem on 19.10, I don't have a `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file! Should I create it? 
And not really sure how to add a route that the article on docker.com is talking about.

Comment: You can just create the `daemon.json` file.

Comment: Also set [`default-address-pools`](https://serverfault.com/a/942176/266986)

Answer (score 0):

`systemd-resolve --status` gave me a DNS server of 192.168.3.56 and `ifconfig docker0` gave me: `inet 192.168.65.2  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 192.168.255.255`
All I had to do was to add /etc/docker/daemon.json as above and restart docker

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it is better that [accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/1380836/1023342), could not look at the update though since link leads to "We can’t connect to the server at success.docker.com", anyway, I solved it in openSUSE Leap 15 with combination of answers [here](https://forums.docker.com/t/cant-access-internet-after-installing-docker-in-a-fresh-ubuntu-18-04-machine/53416/7):

- Get you IP from running `ip a` command, for me look at `inet` line on `eth0`, for instance `inet 42.42.42.42/24 ...`,
- Add `--bip 42.42.42.42/24` (note that in link above `--` are displayed as a single `–` and this may lead to copy/paste wrong stuff) in `ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd ...` line of `/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` file, with example above, change:

  - From `ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --add-runtime oci=/usr/sbin/docker-runc$DOCKER_NETWORK_OPTIONS $DOCKER_OPTS`
  - To `ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --add-runtime oci=/usr/sbin/docker-runc --bip 42.42.42.42/24 $DOCKER_NETWORK_OPTIONS $DOCKER_OPTS`
- And note that restarting docker service was not enough for me, I had to reboot.

In addition, I'll also try `docker network create --subnet 172.17.0.0/16 --config-only do_not_use` from [accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/1380836/1023342), look at it for more details.