# Internet loss after Docker Installation on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, ubuntu, dns, docker

I have installed docker-ce in Ubuntu 16.04 using the [installation guide](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/) given on their official website. Immediately after installing Docker, the host machine can no longer connect to the internet. For proper internet connectivity, I have to remove `docker-ce` and reboot.

This question may seem similar to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1336567/installing-docker-ce-in-ubuntu-18-04-breaks-internet-connectivity-of-host), but the method described in that does not work.

I tried several things:

1. I'm able to ping 8.8.8.8, but not www.google.com.
2. I tried to switch off the network manager by commenting the line `dns=dnsmasq` in `\etc\NetworkManager\NetworkManager.conf`. This didn't work.
3. I tried to make `8.8.8.8` as the first nameserver in `\etc\resolv.conf`. This works, but is lost after reboot, as mentioned in the file.
4. To make the above change permanent, I have used several methods like adding `nameserver 8.8.8.8` to the `head` file under `\etc\resolvconf\resolv.conf.d` and adding `server=8.8.8.8` to `\etc\dnsmasq.conf`. These methods, from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128220/how-do-i-set-my-dns-when-resolv-conf-is-being-overwritten/163506#163506), provide internet connectivity intermittently, and at a very slow speed. This connection keeps breaking.

The default nameserver in `etc\resolv.conf` is 127.0.0.1. This does not change when installing\removing Docker.

**Current environment**

```
parth@parth-Inspiron-5565:/etc$ sudo docker info
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 0
Server Version: 18.09.3
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: e6b3f5632f50dbc4e9cb6288d911bf4f5e95b18e
runc version: 6635b4f0c6af3810594d2770f662f34ddc15b40d
init version: fec3683
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.15.0-46-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 15.13GiB
Name: parth-Inspiron-5565
ID: R4FN:KR6P:OGYS:SV3X:K7FB:2OPX:YGOU:A5OY:LZ3O:QEQQ:EBRS:TY5F
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
Product License: Community Engine

WARNING: No swap limit support
```

**Docker service status**

```
parth@parth-Inspiron-5565:/etc$ sudo service docker status
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2019-03-20 15:12:09 IST; 5min ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 4803 (dockerd)
    Tasks: 13
   Memory: 31.3M
      CPU: 754ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
           └─4803 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock

Mar 20 15:12:07 parth-Inspiron-5565 dockerd[4803]: time="2019-03-20T15:12:07.811072977+05:30" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support swap memory limit"
Mar 20 15:12:07 parth-Inspiron-5565 dockerd[4803]: time="2019-03-20T15:12:07.811201504+05:30" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period"
Mar 20 15:12:07 parth-Inspiron-5565 dockerd[4803]: time="2019-03-20T15:12:07.811233936+05:30" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime"
Mar 20 15:12:07 parth-Inspiron-5565 dockerd[4803]: time="2019-03-20T15:12:07.812451552+05:30" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Mar 20 15:12:08 parth-Inspiron-5565 dockerd[4803]: time="2019-03-20T15:12:08.754820327+05:30" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.31.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can
Mar 20 15:12:08 parth-Inspiron-5565 dockerd[4803]: time="2019-03-20T15:12:08.945255414+05:30" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Mar 20 15:12:09 parth-Inspiron-5565 dockerd[4803]: time="2019-03-20T15:12:09.316910702+05:30" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=774a1f4 graphdriver(s)=overlay2 version=18.09.3
Mar 20 15:12:09 parth-Inspiron-5565 dockerd[4803]: time="2019-03-20T15:12:09.317457771+05:30" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
Mar 20 15:12:09 parth-Inspiron-5565 dockerd[4803]: time="2019-03-20T15:12:09.649782655+05:30" level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock"
Mar 20 15:12:09 parth-Inspiron-5565 systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
```

**ifconfig**

```
parth@parth-Inspiron-5565:~$ ifconfig
br-c3e01d026d40 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:84:ad:16:49  
          inet addr:192.168.0.1  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:c4:54:a7:3a  
          inet addr:172.31.0.1  Bcast:172.31.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

enp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 28:f1:0e:4a:77:f2  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:9142 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9142 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1539138 (1.5 MB)  TX bytes:1539138 (1.5 MB)

wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 94:53:30:48:08:e3  
          inet addr:192.168.0.109  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::24c0:73d4:1184:f7ff/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:66481 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:34205 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:66056535 (66.0 MB)  TX bytes:5806026 (5.8 MB)
```

**Network Manager interfaces information**

```
parth@parth-Inspiron-5565:~$ sudo nmcli dev show | grep -E 'IP4|DEVICE'
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         br-c3e01d026d40
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.0.1/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         docker0
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         172.31.0.1/16
IP4.GATEWAY:                            
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp2s0
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.0.109/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.0.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.0.1
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp1s0
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         lo
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         127.0.0.1/8
```

**brctl output**

```
parth@parth-Inspiron-5565:~$ brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br-c3e01d026d40     8000.024273663b1c   no      
docker0     8000.0242e83f65e7   no
```

**Laptop configuration**

```
parth@parth-Inspiron-5565:/etc$ cat /etc/*release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.6 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial

parth@parth-Inspiron-5565:/etc$ uname -a
Linux parth-Inspiron-5565 4.15.0-46-generic #49~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 12 17:45:24 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: @Attie I have added the whole output of `ifconfig`.

Comment: In recent versions of NetworkManager, the DNS is per-interface, using `dnsmasq`. Use `nmcli dev show | grep -E 'IP4|DEVICE'` to list IP,  routes and DNS for the interfaces. At worst no need to uninstall docker, you can just disconnect the `docker0` interface in your NM widget. No problems with Docker on my 16.04, but then I may have installed a more recent one that the one from the repos (running Docker 18.06)

Comment: @xenoid I have added the information from `nmcli`. Also, the version of Docker is the latest one (18.09). Could you provide me some links on how to disconnect the `docker0` interface?

Comment: @xenoid I have added the output of the `nmcli` command to the question. Also, I am using Docker 18.09. I did try removing the interfaces from the network manager management by adding them to unmanaged devices in the `NetworkManager.conf` file. It shows all networks, except `wlp2s0` as unmanaged, but the problem still persists.

Comment: I presume `wlp2s0` is your route to the internet? Why is `br-c3e01d026d40` on the same subnet? What is the output of `brctl show`? And why does your router / gateway appear to be yourself (`192.168.0.1` /  `br-c3e01d026d40`)?

Comment: Looks like your br-something device is usurpating the `192.168.0.1/24` range. On my system it is a bridge to `172.18.0.1/16`.  What happens if you disconnect/reconnect the WiFi?

Comment: @Attie I have added the output for `brctl show`. `wlp2s0` is the wifi. As for the rest of the questions, I don't know. Also, I am sorry about the delayed replies. The internet isn't working properly despite using `8.8.8.8` in my `resolv.conf`.

Comment: @xenoid There is no visible effect of disconnecting and then reconnecting to the Wi-Fi. The output of ifconfig remains the same. Is there some other output I should check?

Comment: Does running `ip link set dev br-c3e01d026d40 down` resolve the issue? Does it affect container access? If `br-c3e01d026d40` is owned by docker, then there should be a configuration option somewhere to exclude `192.168.0.0/24` from its pool...

Comment: @Attie No, it does not resolve the issue. The `br-c3e01d026d40` is no longer seen in `ifconfig` but it does not make a difference to the issue. Also, how do I test container access?

Comment: @ParthDoshi Did you ever fix this? I have the exact same problem on Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: @barro32 No. I couldn't find a solution.